# asp.net insert data into DB

Tags: asp.net

```
con.Open();
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into dailyWorkout('"+RadioButton1.Text+"', '"+RadioButton2.Text+"', '"+RadioButton3.Text+"', '"+RadioButton4.Text+"', '"+RadioButton5.Text+"', '"+Label1.Text+"')", con);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hey guys, been working on this website for a while, but I get an error when putting data into the database saying

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

With other stuff that I'm putting same way it works and this does not.

Comment: Please use sql parameters; this code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Please - **STOP** concatenating together your SQL statements! This is (a) open to SQL injection attacks, (b) poor for performance, and (c) causes this kind of problems. Please use **parametrized queries** instead! ***Always***

Comment: Also you didn't specified where to insert (column names) and 'values' keyword. Please check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 3):

You should really really REALLY use parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection (and to boost performance; and avoid issues with type conversions etc.)

So I would recommend using code something like this:

```
// define your *parametrized* SQL statement
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(@Val1, @Val2, @Val3);";

// put SqlConnection and SqlCommand into "using" blocks to ensure proper disposal
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("-your-connection-string-here-"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
     // set the parameters to the values you need 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", "Some String here");
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val2", 42);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val3", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7));

     // open connection, execute query, close connection right away
     conn.Open();
     int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
}
```

Points to remember:

- ***ALWAYS*** use parametrized queries - do NOT concatenate together your SQL statements!
- put the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(...) { ... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal
- always explicitly define the list of columns you want to use in a `SELECT` and also an `INSERT` statement
- open connection as late as possible, execute query, close connection again right away

Answer (score 0):

That will do the job but I strongly advice using Parameters.

```
con.Open();
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into dailyWorkout values ('"+RadioButton1.Text+"', '"+RadioButton2.Text+"', '"+RadioButton3.Text+"', '"+RadioButton4.Text+"', '"+RadioButton5.Text+"', '"+Label1.Text+"')", con);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Instead of the code above you'd better to use

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into dailyWorkout values (@val1, @val2, @val3,@val4,@val5,@val6)", con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1",RadioButton1.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2",RadioButton2.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3",RadioButton3.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4",RadioButton4.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5",RadioButton5.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6",Label1.Text)
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: And I would additionally recommend to **explicitly list** the columns of the table in your `INSERT` statement. Makes things more robust and avoids annoying problems when table structure suddenly changes....

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic: see my response! Use `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, Col3, ......, ColN) VALUES(......)` instead of just specifying the table name and nothing else after that...

Answer (score 0):

Ok its already been mentioned, don't inject parameters like that.
But if you must, the problem is that your final sql string looks like:

```
insert into dailyWorkout('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6')
```

when it should be

```
insert into dailyWorkout(columnName1,columnName2,columnName3,columnName4,columnName5,columnName6)
values('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6')
```

But you should really consider:

```
        var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dailyWorkout(columnName1,columnName2,columnName3,columnName4,columnName5,columnName6) values(@v1, @v2, @v3, @v4, @v5, @v6)", default(SqlConnection));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@v1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButton1.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@v2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButton2.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@v3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButton3.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@v4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButton4.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@v5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButton5.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@v6", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Label1.Text;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```